# Combining an observable with the latest value of another observable

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

I have 2 observables `A` and `B`.

I would like to generate `C` that **emits only when A emits**, with a combination of the value just pushed in `A`, and the most recent value in `B`.

Comment: I'm still looking if there is a built in implantation for what your describing.
your essentally describing this :

http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom 

where the top line is A and the Bottom is B , correct ?

Comment: @eranotzap That's it! It's what I was looking for. I have never used that operator until now. Thank you!

Comment: @SuperJMN I'd like love to know if you find or implement this in C# 
i was not able to find it. 
I can think of how to implement it myself..

Comment: There's a method called `Observable.WithLatestFrom`. Where did you look?

Comment: @Shlomo I didn't even know that method existed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, I think this will do

let's say that **A** is an observable of char and **B** an Observable of int.

A calls on next every 3 sec.
B calls on next every 1 sec.

Take the next from A with the current latest of B.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var chrObservable = CharEnumerable().ToObservable();
        var timer1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        var chrAtInterval = timer1.Zip(chrObservable, (ts,c) => c);

        var numberObservable = NumEnumerable().ToObservable();
        var timer2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        var numberAtInterval = timer2.Zip(numberObservable, (ts,n) => n);

        chrAtInterval.WithLatestFrom(numberAtInterval,(c, n) => new{c,n})
               .Subscribe(pair => Console.WriteLine(pair.c + ":" + pair.n));

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> NumEnumerable()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<char> CharEnumerable()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            yield return (char)(i + 65);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I have implemented in a similar scenario. Your example illustrates the usage perfectly. Thank you!